# Why is my header logo appearing twice in my angular app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

With angular, I have my index.html setup as follows.

```
<html><head>...</head>
<body ng-app="someappname">

            <header>
                <img src="images/hdr_logo.png"  alt="...">
            </header>

            <main>

                <!-- this is where the active view will be placed -->
                <ui-view></ui-view>

            </main>

</body></html>
```

And I have my ui-router setup as follows.

```
    $stateProvider

        .state('index', {
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'IndexController',
            abstract: true
        })

        .state('index.login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
        })
```

Currently, my login.html has nothing but text... simply looks like this.

```
This is my login page
```

However, when I run the application I see that my header logo is being displayed twice. Upon further investigation, I can see that my `<ui-view></ui-view>` actually re-includes the entire index.html again (as well as the text). So there is index.html which has another copy of index.html within the ui-view. My display has the logo displayed twice followed by the text, "This is my login page".

Why is the index.html being included within my ui-view, instead of just the partial?

Answer (score 1):

After much toil and trouble, it seems that problem was to do with the keyword `abstract` not being functional in the versions that I was using. Since, whether I added or removed `abstract` the result was the same. However, after I upgraded my angular and ui-router version... everything works!!!

Comment: Plus one from me! I can sleep better knowing this now. haha :)

Comment: @MatthewCawley Thank you so much buddy. I appreciate it.